# PHP ERROR - Na Conexão com o banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados

[image: Error ao tentar "conectar"]

Conexão com o phpmyadmin HOST (codigo n queria ir):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo da conexão para mandar pro bando de dados:

```
 <?php

include_once("conexao.php");

$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];
$email = $_POST['email'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (usuario, senha, email ) VALUES ('$usuario', '$senha', '$email')";
$salvar = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

mysqli_close($conexao);

?>
```

Totalmente novato nesse assunto, qualquer ajuda agradeceria muito.

Comment: O problema não aparenta estar na conexão com o banco de dados, mas sim que você está rodando o código sem enviar os dados na requisição via POST. Os erros que aparecem são que os índices que você está buscando no array associativo POST não existem.

Comment: Realmente como informado no comentário acima, não exibe erro de conexão com banco de dados (até mesmo porque você para a execução com o trecho ```or die ('Não foi possível conectar'); ``` e sim de que ele não conseguiu identificar as variáveis de índice ```$usuario = $_POST['usuario']; $senha = $_POST['senha']; $email = $_POST['email'];``` . Ou seja, não está obtendo o valor dessas variáveis ou há algum problema ao tentar capturar estes dados que aparentemente estão sendo enviados. Recomendo a postar o código de fron-end de onde você envia estes dados.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente seu HTML não está enviando os dados. Verifique que a tag `form` possua o atributo `method` com o valor `POST` e garanta que dentro do form existam tags `input` ou `select` com os respectivos valores.

> Exemplo

```
<form action="processa.php" method="POST">
     <strong>Usuário</strong> <input type="text" name="usuario" required /><br />
     <strong>Senha</strong> <input type="password" name="senha" required /><br />
     <strong>Email</strong> <input type="email" name="email" required /><br />
     <button type="submit">Salvar Dados</button>
</form>
```